# Flexbox wraping too early?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a flexbox layout with 3 flexbox containers and where one of them has a nested flexbox layout inside of it. The one with the nested flexboxes seems to wrap/break too early, eventhou there is available for space for it to take up. I have tried so many different combinations of flex-grow and flex-shrink on the parent elements that I feel like I'm losing my mind, still I can't shake the feeling that there is a simple solution to this.

It works exactly as I want it when the size of the browser is ~ 1600px but as soon as it resizes to smaller it seems breaks the layout and wraps, even thou there is available space for it to continue maintain it's layout.

I can achieve what I want if I change the flex-grow setting on the parent but then the flexboxes doesn't align anymore, which I want. How do I keep both the alignment and the flexbox-growing?

Correct layout but breaking too early example https://jsfiddle.net/9g5dam6f/

Growing properly but not aligning correctly example https://jsfiddle.net/bctgv7ah/

Here is the code as well for the one that breaks too early, but is correctly aligned:

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-info {
  margin: 0 0px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.2em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-45-info {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.col-26-info {
  width: 26.65%;
  justify-content: end;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: purple;
}

.col-33-info {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.col-50-info {
  width: 51%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2em;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 50%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: left;
}

.columns h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.columns p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.17;
}

.columns a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="col-info col-33-info">

      <h1> TRAILBLAZER </h1>
      <li>Art Direction </li>
      <li>Creative Concept</li>
      <li> Graphic Design </li>
      <li> Web Design </li>
      <li> Web Development </li>
      <li> Visual Effects </li>

    </div>


    <div class="col-info col-45-info">
      <p> Art direction and campaign for design collaboration between international brands Marimekko, Matty Bovan, Nomen Nescio, palmer//harding, Per Götesson, Zandra Rhodes, final-year fashion students at Beckmans College of Design and Stockholm Fashion
        Week. <br> <br> The story of the Trailblazer is the story of the innovator. Inspired by the strong artistic approach of all brand and designers, we created a creative concept inspired by 90’s anime and manga that could fit each collections individuality,
        and where each collection could be the hero in their own world, where they blaze a trail for others to walk on. <br> <br> The final develiberables included: A concept film, campaign photos, lookbook photos, website design and development, digital
        and some material.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-info col-26-info">


      <div class="col col-50-info">
        <li> <a target="_blank" href="https://trailblazer.beckmans.college/"> Visit the web </a> <br>
          <a target="_blank" href="https://vimeo.com/510337626"> Watch the film </a> <br>
          <a target="_blank" href="https://trailblazer.beckmans.college/"> ELLE Magazine </a> <br>
          <a target="_blank" href="https://trailblazer.beckmans.college/"> ArtsThread </a>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div class="col-50-info">
        <li class="col" style="margin:0;">
          Date
          <br> Team </li>
        <li class="col"> 2020 <br> Almir Jasarevic <br> Astrid Askert <br> Elisabet Lindén <br> Saba Mehrabanfar <br> Sofia Hjortberg
        </li>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: To me, both examples behave exactly the same. Could you explain what you mean by _"breaking too early"_. And also the alignment in both fiddles is identical to me.

Comment: You have `gap: 2em` in `.col-50-info`. So it's not wrapping too early. You ordered the flexbox to maintain a gap between the elements of `2em` (32px with font-size 16px) and if smaller, wrap it.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to update the other jsfiddle link. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/9g5dam6f/

Here it is aligning properly, as I want - but the `gap:2em` makes it break because there is no `flex-grow:1;` enabled. But when I do enable it and `justify-content:end`  then layout stops being "correct". How do I combine these two? So it maintains it's alignment with each other but breaks the same way as it does when `flow-grow:1;` is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `justify: space-between;` and setting a fixed width for the sibling elements.

You can see the working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yrwh062z/2/